# how can i use two renderers in extjs4 javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a field which is numeric and it should be currency is '$' and it has '0.000,00' struct. for currency and number struct'0.000,00' I have to use renderer for both of them. However, two renderers does not work in right way. The last renderer written works. how can I solve this problem?

```
    {
     header: dil('Fiyat'),
     width: 30,
     sortable: true,
     currencySymbol: '$',
     renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney,
     renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.000,00/i'),
     dataIndex: 'fiyat'
}
```

solution:

```
   renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('$0.000,00/i'). it works both currency and format .
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a renderer function:

```
{
    header: dil('Fiyat'),
    width: 30,
    sortable: true,
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        return value; //You can render your value here however you like.
    },
    dataIndex: 'fiyat'
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I still cannot solve the problem because I don't know how to use this parameters

Comment: Try debugging in your IDE/browser and watch the variables. You can modify Johan's example to a custom renderer.

Comment: If you're using Chrome you could also log the variables. console.log(value);

Comment: ok İsolved the problem with renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('$0.000,00/i'),